# Pass various data formats to a Google sheets chart

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, format, dataformat

I have a Google sheets program where different kinds of statistics data are shown on the graph.

I have some **issue with data formats**.

All statistics have different formats: numeric, monetary, %.

For the purpose of showing each data type correctly on the graph I set appropriate format to data cells (after I rewrite data to the other place on the sheet). Then pass this range to the graph. The result - I could see % and $ on the graph, not only numbers.

But I don't like this approach as it is not universal + something got wrong and monetary graph is not shown anymore. Don't see why in the debugger.

Can someone help to resolve this issue? **How would you change approach to handling formats?**

Here's the code re formats:

```js
//First I get format for the written statistic
var dataFormat = sheet.getRange(fromRow, statColumn, numRows).getNumberFormat()

//then goes this crazyness of writing each format separately
//if data is in % format
if (dataFormat == "0.00%") {

  var format = "0%";

  //if data is a number
} else if (dataFormat == "#,##0.00") {

  var format = "0";

} else if (dataFormat == "0.###############") {

  var format = "0";

} else if (dataFormat == "#,##0") {

  var format = "0";

  //dollars format
} else {

  var format = "[$$]#,##0";
};

//then I write format to the cells to pass this range to a graph (embedded chart)
//dataRange is a named range for cells where I write data 
dataRange.setNumberFormat(format)

//range to pass to graph builder
var range = ss.getRangeByName("SetupDataRange")

var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .addRange(range)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the definition of `dataRange`.

Comment: Datarange is just a named range of cells where I write numbers and set appropriate format to further grab this range to pass to a chart builder.

Comment: The problem is setNumberFormat returns a string, so I think the solution would be treating each string to remove the unwanted symbols.

Comment: @Jescanellas I ran my own test code, based on the OP code, and I'm pretty confident that `setNumberFormat(format)` works as might be required. The problem I am having is that we have only a snippet.

Comment: @kiki Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (remove any private or confidential information). Also would you please edit your question to supply all the code for the script. FWIW, I think you could probably afford to ignore the "snippet" feature in the question data entry screen.